# Whois server not returning results?

Tags: php, whois

Hi I have been messing with this Whois script I got of the 'net, and have been messing with variables and arrays for ever trying to figure out why it won't return the whois results for Google and Facebook (i tested google, as this is the obvious one), then tested facebook after learning it is to do with Whois spamming, and people adding google.com subdomains which this script picks up on (the same happens with facebook)...

After doing my homework i managed to get it to return a list of all results (by removing the section of the script that adds the required "=".$domain to the domain variable.

After that, all results were returned, and i learned the script was picking up the Whois server of the first result (which is a google.com.with.added.spam.com) and therefore "google.com" could not be found on the same whois server as "google.com.with.added.spam.com" therefore it is returning blank.

As to fix it I have tried everything from reversing the preg_match_all array (to grab the last whois server) to editing all the variables i can think of..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

And now the code:

```
<?php

$domain = $_GET['domain'];

// For the full list of TLDs/Whois servers see http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/ and http://www.whois365.com/en/listtld/
$whoisservers = array(
    "ac" =>"whois.nic.ac",
    "ae" =>"whois.nic.ae",
    "aero"=>"whois.aero",
    "af" =>"whois.nic.af",
    "ag" =>"whois.nic.ag",
    "al" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "am" =>"whois.amnic.net",
    "arpa" =>"whois.iana.org",
    "as" =>"whois.nic.as",
    "asia" =>"whois.nic.asia",
    "at" =>"whois.nic.at",
    "au" =>"whois.aunic.net",
    "az" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "ba" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "be" =>"whois.dns.be",
    "bg" =>"whois.register.bg",
    "bi" =>"whois.nic.bi",
    "biz" =>"whois.biz",
    "bj" =>"whois.nic.bj",
    "br" =>"whois.registro.br",
    "bt" =>"whois.netnames.net",
    "by" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "bz" =>"whois.belizenic.bz",
    "ca" =>"whois.cira.ca",
    "cat" =>"whois.cat",
    "cc" =>"whois.nic.cc",
    "cd" =>"whois.nic.cd",
    "ch" =>"whois.nic.ch",
    "ci" =>"whois.nic.ci",
    "ck" =>"whois.nic.ck",
    "cl" =>"whois.nic.cl",
    "cn" =>"whois.cnnic.net.cn",
    "com" =>"whois.verisign-grs.com",
    "coop" =>"whois.nic.coop",
    "cx" =>"whois.nic.cx",
    "cy" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "cz" =>"whois.nic.cz",
    "de" =>"whois.denic.de",
    "dk" =>"whois.dk-hostmaster.dk",
    "dm" =>"whois.nic.cx",
    "dz" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "edu" =>"whois.educause.edu",
    "ee" =>"whois.eenet.ee",
    "eg" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "es" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "eu" =>"whois.eu",
    "fi" =>"whois.ficora.fi",
    "fo" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "fr" =>"whois.nic.fr",
    "gb" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "gd" =>"whois.adamsnames.com",
    "ge" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "gg" =>"whois.channelisles.net",
    "gi" =>"whois2.afilias-grs.net",
    "gl" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "gm" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "gov" =>"whois.nic.gov",
    "gr" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "gs" =>"whois.nic.gs",
    "gw" =>"whois.nic.gw",
    "gy" =>"whois.registry.gy",
    "hk" =>"whois.hkirc.hk",
    "hm" =>"whois.registry.hm",
    "hn" =>"whois2.afilias-grs.net",
    "hr" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "hu" =>"whois.nic.hu",
    "ie" =>"whois.domainregistry.ie",
    "il" =>"whois.isoc.org.il",
    "in" =>"whois.inregistry.net",
    "info" =>"whois.afilias.net",
    "int" =>"whois.iana.org",
    "io" =>"whois.nic.io",
    "iq" =>"vrx.net",
    "ir" =>"whois.nic.ir",
    "is" =>"whois.isnic.is",
    "it" =>"whois.nic.it",
    "je" =>"whois.channelisles.net",
    "jobs" =>"jobswhois.verisign-grs.com",
    "jp" =>"whois.jprs.jp",
    "ke" =>"whois.kenic.or.ke",
    "kg" =>"www.domain.kg",
    "ki" =>"whois.nic.ki",
    "kr" =>"whois.nic.or.kr",
    "kz" =>"whois.nic.kz",
    "la" =>"whois.nic.la",
    "li" =>"whois.nic.li",
    "lt" =>"whois.domreg.lt",
    "lu" =>"whois.dns.lu",
    "lv" =>"whois.nic.lv",
    "ly" =>"whois.nic.ly",
    "ma" =>"whois.iam.net.ma",
    "mc" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "md" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "me" =>"whois.meregistry.net",
    "mg" =>"whois.nic.mg",
    "mil" =>"whois.nic.mil",
    "mn" =>"whois.nic.mn",
    "mobi" =>"whois.dotmobiregistry.net",
    "ms" =>"whois.adamsnames.tc",
    "mt" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "mu" =>"whois.nic.mu",
    "museum" =>"whois.museum",
    "mx" =>"whois.nic.mx",
    "my" =>"whois.mynic.net.my",
    "na" =>"whois.na-nic.com.na",
    "name" =>"whois.nic.name",
    "net" =>"whois.verisign-grs.net",
    "nf" =>"whois.nic.nf",
    "nl" =>"whois.domain-registry.nl",
    "no" =>"whois.norid.no",
    "nu" =>"whois.nic.nu",
    "nz" =>"whois.srs.net.nz",
    "org" =>"whois.pir.org",
    "pl" =>"whois.dns.pl",
    "pm" =>"whois.nic.pm",
    "pr" =>"whois.uprr.pr",
    "pro" =>"whois.registrypro.pro",
    "pt" =>"whois.dns.pt",
    "re" =>"whois.nic.re",
    "ro" =>"whois.rotld.ro",
    "ru" =>"whois.ripn.net",
    "sa" =>"whois.nic.net.sa",
    "sb" =>"whois.nic.net.sb",
    "sc" =>"whois2.afilias-grs.net",
    "se" =>"whois.iis.se",
    "sg" =>"whois.nic.net.sg",
    "sh" =>"whois.nic.sh",
    "si" =>"whois.arnes.si",
    "sk" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "sm" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "st" =>"whois.nic.st",
    "su" =>"whois.ripn.net",
    "tc" =>"whois.adamsnames.tc",
    "tel" =>"whois.nic.tel",
    "tf" =>"whois.nic.tf",
    "th" =>"whois.thnic.net",
    "tj" =>"whois.nic.tj",
    "tk" =>"whois.dot.tk",
    "tl" =>"whois.nic.tl",
    "tm" =>"whois.nic.tm",
    "tn" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "to" =>"whois.tonic.to",
    "tp" =>"whois.nic.tl",
    "tr" =>"whois.nic.tr",
    "travel" =>"whois.nic.travel",
    "tv" => "tvwhois.verisign-grs.com",
    "tw" =>"whois.twnic.net.tw",
    "ua" =>"whois.net.ua",
    "ug" =>"whois.co.ug",
    "uk" =>"whois.nic.uk",
    "us" =>"whois.nic.us",
    "uy" =>"nic.uy",
    "uz" =>"whois.cctld.uz",
    "va" =>"whois.ripe.net",
    "vc" =>"whois2.afilias-grs.net",
    "ve" =>"whois.nic.ve",
    "vg" =>"whois.adamsnames.tc",
    "wf" =>"whois.nic.wf",
    "ws" =>"whois.website.ws",
    "yt" =>"whois.nic.yt",
    "yu" =>"whois.ripe.net");

function LookupDomain($domain){
    global $whoisservers;
    $domain_parts = explode(".", $domain);
    $tld = strtolower(array_pop($domain_parts));
    $whoisserver = $whoisservers[$tld];
    if(!$whoisserver) {
        return "Error: No appropriate Whois server found for $domain domain!";
    }
    $result = QueryWhoisServer($whoisserver, $domain);
    if(!$result) {
        return "Error: No results retrieved from $whoisserver server for $domain domain!";
    }
    else {
        while(strpos($result, "Whois Server:") !== FALSE){
            preg_match("/Whois Server: (.*)/", $result, $matches);
            $secondary = $matches[1];
            if($secondary) {
                $result = QueryWhoisServer($secondary, $domain);
                $whoisserver = $secondary;
            }
        }
    }
    return "$domain domain lookup results from $whoisserver server:\n\n" . $result;
}

function LookupIP($ip) {
    $whoisservers = array(
        //"whois.afrinic.net", // Africa - returns timeout error :-(
        "whois.lacnic.net", // Latin America and Caribbean - returns data for ALL locations worldwide :-)
        "whois.apnic.net", // Asia/Pacific only
        "whois.arin.net", // North America only
        "whois.ripe.net" // Europe, Middle East and Central Asia only
    );
    $results = array();
    foreach($whoisservers as $whoisserver) {
        $result = QueryWhoisServer($whoisserver, $ip);
        if($result && !in_array($result, $results)) {
            $results[$whoisserver]= $result;
        }
    }
    $res = "RESULTS FOUND: " . count($results);
    foreach($results as $whoisserver=>$result) {
        $res .= "\n\n-------------\nLookup results for $ip from $whoisserver server:\n\n$result";
    }
    return $res;
}

function ValidateIP($ip) {
    $ipnums = explode(".", $ip);
    if(count($ipnums) != 4) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach($ipnums as $ipnum) {
        if(!is_numeric($ipnum) || ($ipnum > 255)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $ip;
}

function ValidateDomain($domain) {
    if(!preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9]{2,100})\.([a-z\.]{2,8})$/i", $domain)) {
        return false;
    }
    return $domain;
}

function QueryWhoisServer($whoisserver, $domain) {
    $port = 43;
    $timeout = 10;
    $fp = @fsockopen($whoisserver, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout) or die("Socket Error " . $errno . " - " . $errstr);
    if($whoisserver == "whois.verisign-grs.com") $domain = "=".$domain; // whois.verisign-grs.com requires the equals sign ("=") or it returns any result containing the searched string.
    fputs($fp, $domain . "\r\n");
    $out = "";
    while(!feof($fp)){
        $out .= fgets($fp);
    }
    fclose($fp);

    $res = "";
    if((strpos(strtolower($out), "error") === FALSE) && (strpos(strtolower($out), "not allocated") === FALSE)) {
        $rows = explode("\n", $out);
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $row = trim($row);
            if(($row != '') && ($row{0} != '#') && ($row{0} != '%')) {
                $res .= $row."\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Whois Lookup Script</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<p><b><label for="domain">Domain/IP Address:</label></b> <input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" value="<?=$domain;?>"> <input type="submit" value="Lookup"></p>
</form>
<?
if($domain) {
    $domain = trim($domain);
    if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 7) == "http://") $domain = substr($domain, 7);
    if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 4) == "www.") $domain = substr($domain, 4);
    if(ValidateIP($domain)) {
        $result = LookupIP($domain);
    }
    elseif(ValidateDomain($domain)) {
        $result = LookupDomain($domain);
    }
    else die("Invalid Input!");
    echo "<pre>\n" . $result . "\n</pre>\n";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are trying to send the domain(For example:google.com) to your script from the form, instead of sending it as 'google.com' add the word 'domain' i.e(domain google.com).

What this does, it tells the whois server to find this domain(i.e google.com) and not any other domain that has  the word google in it.

So in the function "LookupDomain($domain)" be sure that the value of $domain should be 
'domain google.com' for it to display the proper result.

Answer (score 2):

change the .com server to "whois.crsnic.net" and it should work

Answer (score 2):

This script not working yet. so you can try the following code

```
<?php function whois_query($domain)
{

 // fix the domain name:
 $domain = strtolower(trim($domain));
 $domain = preg_replace('/^http:\/\//i', '', $domain);
 $domain = preg_replace('/^www\./i', '', $domain);
 $domain = explode('/', $domain);
 $domain = trim($domain[0]);

 // split the TLD from domain name
 $_domain = explode('.', $domain);
 $lst = count($_domain)-1;
 $ext = $_domain[$lst];

 // the list of whois servers
 // most taken from www.iana.org/domains/root/db/
 $servers = array(
  "biz" => "whois.neulevel.biz",
  "com" => "whois.internic.net",
  "us" => "whois.nic.us",
  "coop" => "whois.nic.coop",
  "info" => "whois.nic.info",
  "name" => "whois.nic.name",
  "net" => "whois.internic.net",
  "gov" => "whois.nic.gov",
  "edu" => "whois.internic.net",
  "mil" => "rs.internic.net",
  "int" => "whois.iana.org",
  "ac" => "whois.nic.ac",
  "ae" => "whois.uaenic.ae",
  "at" => "whois.ripe.net",
  "au" => "whois.aunic.net",
  "be" => "whois.dns.be",
  "bg" => "whois.ripe.net",
  "br" => "whois.registro.br",
  "bz" => "whois.belizenic.bz",
  "ca" => "whois.cira.ca",
  "cc" => "whois.nic.cc",
  "ch" => "whois.nic.ch",
  "cl" => "whois.nic.cl",
  "cn" => "whois.cnnic.net.cn",
  "cz" => "whois.nic.cz",
  "de" => "whois.nic.de",
  "fr" => "whois.nic.fr",
  "hu" => "whois.nic.hu",
  "ie" => "whois.domainregistry.ie",
  "il" => "whois.isoc.org.il",
  "in" => "whois.ncst.ernet.in",
  "ir" => "whois.nic.ir",
  "mc" => "whois.ripe.net",
  "to" => "whois.tonic.to",
  "tv" => "whois.tv",
  "ru" => "whois.ripn.net",
  "org" => "whois.pir.org",
  "aero" => "whois.information.aero",
  "nl" => "whois.domain-registry.nl",
  "uk" => "whois.nic.uk",
  "us" => "whois.nic.us",
  "travel" => "whois.nic.travel",
  "gov" => "whois.dotgov.gov",
  "it" => "whois.nic.it"
 );

 if (!isset($servers[$ext])) {
  die('Error: No matching whois server found!');
 }

 $nic_server = $servers[$ext];

 $output = '';

 // connect to whois server:
 if ($conn = fsockopen($nic_server, 43)) {
  fwrite($conn, $domain."\r\n");
  while (!feof($conn)) {
   $output .= fgets($conn, 128);
  }
  fclose($conn);
 } else {
  die('Error: Could not connect to ' . $nic_server . '!');
 }
 return $output;
}
echo '<pre>'.whois_query('google.com').'</pre>';
?>
```